# How do I retrieve an array from a dictionary which and then retrieve a dictionary within that array?

Tags: iphone, ios, xml, xcode, nsdictionary

I would like to know how to retrieve an array from within a dictionary and then retrieve the dictionary from the array object.

i'm following this http://ios.biomsoft.com/2011/09/11/simple-xml-to-nsdictionary-converter/

```
itemDict 
 (
        {
        postID =         {
            text = 26;
        };
        score =         {
            text = 20;
        };
        title =         {
            text = "http://www.google.com quiz";
        };
        url =         {
            text = "http://www.google.com";
        };
    },
        {
        postID =         {
            text = 27;
        };
        score =         {
            text = 10;
        };
        title =         {
            text = "http://www.google.com";
        };
        url =         {
            text = "http://www.google.com";
        };
    },
        {
        postID =         {
            text = 3;
        };
        score =         {
            text = 41;
        };
        title =         {
            text = "http://www.google.com";
        };
        url =         {
            text = "http://www.google.com";
        };
    },
        {
        postID =         {
            text = 35;
        };
        score =         {
            text = 10;
        };
        title =         {
            text = "Sample Video";
        };
        url =         {
            text = "http://www.google.com";
        };
    },
        {
        postID =         {
            text = 43;
        };
        score =         {
            text = 30;
        };
        title =         {
            text = "sample";
        };
        url =         {
            text = "http://www.google.com";
        };
    }
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alrighty, what you want to do is the following.

From what I can gather from the link posted as well, you have a top level `NSDictionary` which then contains the XML inside it. There would be an object inside the `NSDictionary` which would, from your example, be `itemDict` but that, to my eyes, looks more like an NSArray.

From here, I'd store that `NSArray` inside another one.

Each object inside that array is an `NSDictionary` of keys and objects matched to them. Obviously I'm talking about this bit.

```
{
    postID =         {
        text = 26;
    };
    score =         {
        text = 20;
    };
    title =         {
        text = "http://www.google.com quiz";
    };
    url =         {
        text = "http://www.google.com";
    };
},
```

Maybe something like the following will let you dive down deep enough.

```
NSArray *itemArray = [xmlDictionary objectForKey:@"itemDict"];

for (NSDictionary *dict in itemArray) {

    NSLog(@"Dictionary: %@", dict);

}
```

That code should show the output of each NSDictionary inside the NSArray. From here it is a simple case of doing whatever you want with the NSDictionary.

**EDIT**

Just had another look and thought I'd add this in as well.
It seems each NSDictionary we would make with the above code, then has a key for another object and that object is stored inside another dictionary. Something really weird with the XML if you ask me...

But, a work around could be the following.

```
NSArray *itemArray = [xmlDictionary objectForKey:@"itemDict"];

for (NSDictionary *dict in itemArray) {

    NSLog(@"Dictionary: %@", dict);

    for (NSDictionary *dictObject in [dict allKeys]) {

         NSLog(@"Dictionary Object: %@", dictObject);

    }

}
```

If this isn't what you're wanting to do, please edit your question so I can rectify my response.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

Lets suppose you parse it and have something like this:

```
    (
//object 0
    {
    postID= 26;
    score = 20;
    title = www.google.com
    url = www.google.com
    },
//object 1
    {
    postID= 27;
    score = 10;
    title = www.google.com
    url = www.google.com
    }...
    )
```

This is your array.

The objectAtIndex:0 which in this example is:

```
{
postID= 26;
score = 20;
title = www.google.com
url = www.google.com
}
```

is a dictionary.